# Get most frequently used many to many field

Tags: sql, django, database, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # and other fields ...

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    # and other fields 

class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
```

And few other models have tags as ManyToMany field. I would like to get the list of most used tag objects. I tried to filter most frequently used tags from each model and then getting top ten from each and combining them with other top ten. I think there should be something I could do from 'Tag' model itself to find the most used tag instances.

Is there any way of finding the most used tag instances except my approach ? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Most used tag objects among all these elements? Or among just one type of element? The latter is more complicated (and will usually require a large amount of querying)

Comment: What I wanted to do is in front page I want to get 2 articles, 2 books and few other models based on the most used tags . So to answer your question I think its getting most used tag objects among all these elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you want the top 10 of tags used by `Book`s, then you can query this like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Tag.objects.annotate(
    nused=Count('book')
).order_by('-nused')[:10]
```

We thus query the database for `Tag`s that we order by the number of related books for each tag.

We can use multiple counts, but by using them in one query, this will typically generate an expensive query: in that case you will `JOIN` on all these related models, and as a result, the time complexity of the query will typically grow exponential in the number of models. Although it is possible that some database managers find out that these are "*independent*" subqueries, my experience that popular ones usually do not. So we better use multiple queries here: one per related model.

So now we first need to find out what the related models are. Luckily Django provides some utility functions for that. Every model class has a `._meta` object that stores information about the model. One of these attribute is `.fields_map`, which returns a dictionary that maps the name of relations to the relation object.

We can use this to enumerate over the relations, and thus for every relation use a query:

```
from collections import Counter
from django.db.models import Count

cntr = Counter()
for relation in Tag._meta.fields_map:
    cntr.update(
        {
            tg: tg.nr
            for tg in Tag.objects.annotate(nr=Count(relation)).order_by('nr')[:10]
        }
    )
```

At the end, we will have a `Counter` that contains, for these tags, the total number of occurrences. Note however that since we each time limit the number to 10.

We can then obtain the most popular tags by obtaining the most common from the counter:

```
from operator import itemgetter

my_tags = map(itemgetter(0), ca.most_common(10))
```

The `.most_common(10)` will generate the top 10 of tags (by summing up the rank of the most common per relation), and return a list of 2-tuples: every tuple contains the `Tag` instance, and the number of uses. By using a `map(itemgetter(0), ...)`, we only obtain the `Tag`s. But you might be interested in the numbers as well.

## Why limiting *per* relation might be a bad idea...

This does *not* mean that we per se have the most frequent tag. Indeed, say that a tag is the 11-th most popular tag for `Book`s, and `Article`s, then this still can be the overall most popular tag, since it is possible that the top 10 of `Book`s and `Article`s is totally different. Or a small example:

```
Top Books    Top Articles
1. A (10)    1. D (12)
2. B (8)     2. E (8)
3. C (7)     3. C (7)
```

If we would generate a top 2 with the above approach, we thus would miss `C` that actually occurs most (`14` times in total).

We can solve this problem by simply always counting all `Tag`s, and thus remove the `[:10]` limit:

```
from collections import Counter
from django.db.models import Count

cntr = Counter()
for relation in Tag._meta.fields_map:
    cntr.update(
        {
            tg: tg.nr
            for tg in Tag.objects.annotate(nr=Count(relation)).order_by('nr')
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

list of 10 most used tag in book model:

```
tags_of_book = Tag.objects.all().annotate(num_book = Count('book')).order_by('-num_book')[:10]
```

list of 10 most used tag in article model:

```
tags_of_article = Tag.objects.all().annotate(num_article = Count('article')).order_by('-num_article')[:10]
```

Comment: Your solution is what I came up with.
 But what if I want only top ten tags used everywhere. What I did was find top ten tags for Book , then article and other models and combining them to get only top ten. 
what I want is :
Currently if 'python' tag is used 50 times only in 'Book'. This tag won't come up if I search it in other model except 'Book'. However since it has been used 50 times (say count of other tags is less than 50 ), it should be displayed when I search for most used tags. Now if 'python' tag is not used at all in 'Article' it won't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `annotate()` to have the tags ordered by amount of time they are used in `Article` (can do the same for `Book`):

```
Tag.objects.all().annotate(
    nb_articles=Count("article_set"),
).order_by("-nb_articles")
```

However, getting the most used tag among both `Article` and `Book` will require either more queries or something fancier using probably [Subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) (see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/))

Comment: This will unfortunately act like a *mutliplier*: both counts will be the same, the number of articles *times* the number of books. This is due to the fact that we perform a double JOIN, and thus count the same book multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get common tags and and i found the previous answers but in my case i was creating template tags and i had multiple models so I had a little of engineering after several trials.

I hope this helps anyone using multiple models and want to find common tags across all  models

```
    hot_tags=Tag.objects.annotate(nused=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items')).order_by('-nused')[:5]
```

`taggit_taggeditem_items` is table column containing all the tags. It is from the `django-taggit` package